# Why I can't set title with NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Why I can't set title with NSString ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *getProvince = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",g_province];
    NSLog(@"getProvince %@",getProvince);
    self.title = @"%@",getProvince;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

g_province is from other file (xxxx.m) and It's NSString.

And NSLog show "getProvince 東京" and It's correct. But it didn't show in title.

Comment: You don't need to use `stringWithFormat:` if you are just providing another string... just use `self.title = g_province;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chnage it to : self.title = getProvince;

Comment: OP was overcomplicating things - your answer works and is correct.

Comment: It's still overcomplicated though - if g_province is an NSString, as the OP says, there's no need to create the getProvince copy of it at all.

Comment: You need to use NSString only if there is any additional text or formatting you need to add or append to the string you want to display as title. If no formatting is required, you can directly assign the string to self.title

Answer (score 1):

mistake is somewhere else

```
NSString *getProvince = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",g_province];
NSLog(@"getProvince %@",getProvince);
self.title = getProvince;
```

if not works then try

```
self.title = @"Hello";
```

if it works let me know

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any formatting to g_province, so the -stringWithFormat: is unnecessary. Just use g_province directly:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"g_province %@", g_province);
    self.title = g_province;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code

following line

```
self.title = @"%@",getProvince;
```

must be like

```
self.title = getProvince;
```

Comment: Pls avoid providing duplicate answers. And use code formatting.